# select count query

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE a_b
(
 a_b_id integer NOT NULL,
 name text NOT NULL
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE a
(
 a_b_id integer NOT NULL,
 status text NOT NULL
)
```

and values are:

### table a_b:

```
a_b_id   name 
  1      aaa
  2      bbb
  3      ccc
```

### table a:

```
a_b_id   status
  1      ACTIVE
  1      ACTIVE
  1      ACTIVE
  1      DELETED
  2      DELETED
```

And I try to select values from table 'a_b' with count of related values from table 'a' with no 'DELETED'  status.
I'm trying to do:

```
select ab.name, count(a.a_b_id) from a_b ab left join a a on ab.a_b_id=a.a_b_id
where a.status != 'DELETED' GROUP BY ab.a_b_id,ab.name
```

But actual result is:

```
aaa   3
```

Expected result is:

```
aaa 3
bbb 0
ccc 0
```

So how I have to modify my query to receive my expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `where` clause turns your `left join` into an `inner join`. Put the condition in the `on` clause of your join

```
select ab.name, 
       count(a.a_b_id) 
from a_b ab 
left join a a on ab.a_b_id = a.a_b_id
             and a.status != 'DELETED'
GROUP BY ab.a_b_id, ab.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use a sub-query to count:

```
select a_b.name, (select count(*) from a
                  where a.a_b_id = a_b.a_b_id
                    and a.status != 'DELETED')
from a_b;
```